# What happens if a GPIO "in" pin is accidentally configured as "out"?

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I have a 433MHz receiver connected to a GIPO pin (which is configure as "IN"). I was wondering what happens if the GPIO is accidentally configured as "OUT" during reboot, shutdown, or when another application is running (not my application).

So can it happen that my RASPI (3 in my case) gets damaged during shutdown/restart when the GPIO pin randomly is set to "OUT" mode?

Here an example of such a "random" pin situation: [Why is GPIO 16 on at boot?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/24109/47892)

Comment: GPIO will never be  **accidentally** configured as OUT - you would have to do something specifically to set it; **ALL** GPIO are INPUT on boot, until reconfigured. In the obsolete example you linked this was explicitly set by the OS code.

Comment: Ok, true from the OS side and thanks for the hint. But for instance if i run another program which sets it to OUT (even without my knowledge) or I just make make a mistake and accidentally set it to OUT while the receiver is still connected, is there some kind of protection?